6T SRAM Simulation on Cadence
I had recently studied about SRAM in Computer Architecture and learned that a SRAM Cell is actually made up of MOSFETs. I was curious to learn more about the architecture of SRAM, for which I read some Journal Articles on 6T SRAM Cell and decided to simulate it on Cadence. I just wanted to confirm if the simulation of the graph for the SNM of Standby Mode and Read Mode looks correct?




As, we can see here I intentionally kept the Width of the PMOS double because of the fact that the holes mobility is slower than electrons. Can you please assist with this?
VALUES:
VDD: 1.8 V
WL(Pulse Voltage): V1 = 0,V2 = 1, Period = 4u
BL(Pulse Voltage): V1 = 1,V2 = 0, Period = 2u
BLB(Pulse Voltage): V1 = 1, V2 = 0, Period = 2u
Note: The reason the BL and BLB are same is because I want both Bit Line (BL) and Bit Line Bar (BLB) to initially start from 1. Then one can stay at 1 and the other one can discharge accordingly.
Also net39 refers to Node Q for Bit Line and net42 refers to Node Q_Bar for Bit line Bar.
Here, I am trying to plot or simulate the DC Analysis by taking a Component Parameter into account which is by the name of: V0.
Thank you,

Maybe it is clearer to show the result of a transient simulation which shows WL, BL, BLB, net39, and net42.

@JackBlack, I have added the transient analysis screenshot from Cadence as well. Another question I had was, I put the BL and BLB's Volatges as V1 = 1 and V2 = 0. I suppose they should be opposite right?

Yes, they should have opposite polarity. Also, BL, BLB and WL should be 1.8V as a digital '1'. You may also want to remove the voltage source V0 if you've finished the SNM simulation. For read mode, you set WL high and read BL and BLB - they should be opposite and represent the message stored in the cell. You don't need to set BL and BLB in read mode, you only set/reset BL in the write mode.

@JackBlack, Thank you for your reply. I am able to successfully write into the cell and simulate it. However, I am still having an issue while simulating the Read Mode. The Pins Bit Line and Bit Line Bar that I made are of type InputOutput, So after I write let’s say Q=1 and Q_bar=0. Then I try to read by disabling the BL and BLB as inputs but the simulated graph I get shows same values for both BL and BLB.

What do you mean by disabling the BL and BLB? Did you set them to 0 at the same time? I would think that any voltage sources on BL and BLB should be disconnected in read mode. Perhaps 2 more switches could be added to make this possible.

So Before simulating, We can change the parameters for the pins right, so there I disable the BL and BLB but that didn’t work. However, I did read somewhere that for Read Mode, we need the BL and BLB to be set to high initially, along with WL = 1.
